# Can I change SSHD config properties through command line?

Tags: bash, debian, ubuntu, ssh, ansible

I have about 20 ubuntu/debian VMs.
When I originally set them all up I was using ssh password authentication.

I want to change all of them to use key authentication only.

`PermitRootLogin yes` >> `PermitRootLogin ProhibitPassword`

Do I need to manually go on each server and nano etc/ssh/sshd_config and change it to prohibit-password or can I bulk update all of the VMs through ansible/bash?

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/701684/how-to-change-the-value-of-system-files-without-opening-them

Found it here nevermind. A command exists to do it. `sed`

And it looks like ansible has a built in `replace` module to do the same.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html